# Android: save a large number of photos from url

Tags: android, caching, data-storage

I'm making the mobile version of an online store and i have to make it available when offline.

The problem is with photos: the store might have a large number of products, thus photos.

What method of saving the images should i use considering that a phone has some hardware limitation?

What I want is

1. As small as possible occupied memory with ok performance at reading it.
2. Writing speed is also something to be considered since downloading so much data will take some time and the user might decide it's not worth the wait(this is a secondary problem though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `Universal Image Loader`
In my application i load more than 300 photos and i don't get outOfMemoryException error however the library needs to draw some cache. 
Here's the project on GitHub:

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: how about memory usage, how much per photo? for image size of something like this (hope you get it):final int REQUIRED_SIZE=250;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

Comment: it's okay. My required size is 500 as well. :)

Comment: sounds good, although I have aprox 0.75 MB from about 10 pictures and I'm kind of worried about this. The question now is how much space should I use? I can get it to use a smaller amount per photo if there are large number of them.

Comment: my application draw 25 mb of cache when loading images. But i clear the cache once i destroy the activity
Add onDestroy method to your application then clear the cache once the app is destroyed.

Comment: will the cache ever be cleared? not talking about the user manually doing this, will the phone ever clear that data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36387/discussion-between-kingomar-and-mihai-bratulescu)

Answer (score 3):

you can try aquery android library for lazy loading image and its also store images in cache memory so you not need to store it externally...below code may help you.....

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(mContext);
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://data.whicdn.com/images/63995806/original.jpg");
```

You can download library from [from this link](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar)

Comment: ok but looking at the code I see you need to give it am ImageView or something before saving it into the cache and load the image there, and I have seen this at some other code, can you somehow get the image from cache that you need?

Comment: When you first time load images from web it will take some time for loading with progress showing and then after it take very short time to load so you can get better performance...also given link helps you how to implement your code...just import library .jar in your libs and by writing few lines of code you can get result...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Google Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) for handling networking and image loading. 
It's a very powerful yet super simple interface for accomplishing all you network needs without worrying about implementation details.

You have 2 built  in levels of caching out of the box, and you can always add your own.